# Get directory size ssh2 php

Tags: php, size, ssh2-exec

I need to work out how i can get a directory size of a folder.

Code that **does work** is taken from php.net

```
$SSH_CONNECTION= ssh2_connect('xx.xxx.xx.xx', xx);
ssh2_auth_password($SSH_CONNECTION, 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');

function scanFilesystem($dir) {
    $tempArray = array();
    $handle = opendir($dir);
  // List all the files
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (substr("$file", 0, 1) != "."){
           if(is_dir($file)){
            $tempArray[$file]=scanFilesystem("$dir/$file");
        } else {
            $tempArray[]=$file;
        }
    }
    }
   closedir($handle);
  return $tempArray;
}


$sftp = ssh2_sftp($SSH_CONNECTION);

//code to get listing of all OUTGOING files
$dir = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp//home/user/mail/websiteaddress.com.au/janedoe";
$outgoing = scanFilesystem($dir);
sort($outgoing);
print_r($outgoing);
```

So I get a result from print_r but now how do i get the folder size of janedoe?

The output of $outgoing is:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(3) "cur" 
[1]=> string(11) "maildirsize" 
[2]=> string(3) "new" 
[3]=> string(3) "tmp" 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by folder size? The number of files in the folder?

Comment: @Barmar I mean the folder size in megabytes or kb

Comment: Use `stat("$dir/$file")` to get information about the file, which includes the file size. Add this into a `$total_size` variable.

Comment: BTW, `is_dir($file)` should be `is_dir("$dir/$file")`.

Comment: @Barmar thankyou for your advice. Im stumped for examples on how to use that correctly. Can you please provide me an example.

Comment: If you mean like this ---- $total_size = fstat("$dir/$file");

echo $total_size; ----- It wont work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a filesize accumulator to your return array:

```
function scanFilesystem($dir) {
    $tempArray = array();
    $tempArray['total_size'] = 0;
    $handle = opendir($dir);
  // List all the files
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (substr("$file", 0, 1) != "."){
           if(is_dir($file)){
            $tempArray[$file]=scanFilesystem("$dir/$file");
            $tempArray['total_size'] += $tempArray[$file]['total_size'];
        } else {
            $tempArray[]=$file;
            $tempArray['total_size'] += filesize("$dir/$file");
        }
    }
    }
   closedir($handle);
  return $tempArray;
}
```

Comment: To get the total size, after the recursion you'll need to add its total size to the total size at this level.

Comment: `$tempArray['total_size'] += $tempArray[$file]['total_size'];`

Comment: John McMahon Thankyou @Barmar before the last bracket or after?

Comment: Im stuck on the lats bit LOL. Im getting sizes im just having trouble outputting one total number.

Comment: @JohnRama It's in `$outgoing['total_size']`

Comment: @Barmar and John - so who do i green tick now? It worked but with both of your help :)

Comment: @JohnRama IMO marking answers is mostly a mechanism to help folks with a similar issue who might stumble upon this in the future. If this answer was helpful but needs changes please make a suggestion or edit.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon it seems that it wont give me a folder size if there are other folders inside it. I have a folders like so janedoe/cur,new,tmp,.sent,.junk etc... Is it possible to get a grand total of all sub directories even if there is a dot at the start of folders?

Comment: This line is excluding directories that begin with a period: `if (substr("$file", 0, 1) != "."){` You would need to add logic to recursively go through those to get file sizes but not add the files to your array.